# Web framework для языка c/c++

Tags: c++, c, веб-программирование, nginx, websocket

Здравствуйте!
Вопрос такой. Собираюсь писать приложение где требуется что бы все работало очень быстро. Приложение клиент-серверное. В серверной части думаю будет Nginx+websocket, приложение естественно с/c++. 
Теперь вопрос стал о web framework'e. Если для случая с python все понятно (nginx+tornado+django), то тут не очень в силу того, что не приходилось даже задумываться о таком. Google активно предлагает Kore.io.
Суть вопроса: 
Кто имел подобный опыт работы язык С и web и что из этого вышло?
Какие есть еще варианты web framework для языка С?

Comment: Вообще странно, что вы не делаете различий между С и С++. Разные языки, разные подходы. Какая конечная цель? *Быстрая работа*? Вы уверены, что достаточно хорошо знаете эти языки, чтобы обеспечить эффективное использование ресурсов? С и С++ эффективны, если вы знаете, что и как делать. Сделать с их помощью неэффективное решение гораздо проще, чем на том же пайтоне.

Comment: @user1056837 Ваше замечание справедливо. Однако прежде чем приступить к работе, хотелось бы узнать максим информации. А потом выбрать более подходящий и предварительно подготовить свои знания перед реализацией. У меня нет задачи написать приложение в сжатые сроки и по этому есть время усовершенствовать свои навыки в любом из языков. Почему не Python: мне нужен низкоуровневый язык, а не интерпретатор. Там будут задействованы разные железки такие как stm или atmel он же Arduino. Предыдущая реализация была на raspberry с python. Результат не устроил. Моя цель получить быструю работу железки.

Comment: @user1056837 при этом необходим клиент серверный подход. Если у Вас есть идеи было бы любопытно взглянуть на них через мою призму. Web server, raspberry, Arduino, клиент

Comment: boost::asio, POCO - наиболее известные сетевые библотеки для С++. Но я совсем не уверен, что С++ - хороший выбор.

Comment: @user1056837 если есть желание хотелось бы услышать ваше видение решения. Пока писал пришла в голову мысль. Nginx+ tornado+ Python+ (raspberry+ Arduino(Cpp)) но не слишком ли длинная цепочка.

Answer (score 2):

Я имел опыт написания многопоточный Web сервера на С++ (использовал фреймворк Qt5). Получилась очень стабильная надёжная, а главное гибкая в плане нагрузки штука. Главное использовать такой класс как `QThreadPool` Использование этого класса освобождает прогера от головной боли из-за того что его web сервер занял слишком много оперативки из-за большой кол-во потоков. Класс `QThreadPool` сам будет контролировать нагрузки.

Comment: Спасибо. Обязательно посмотрю. А про kore.io Вам что нибудь известно?

Comment: Слышал что это фрейморк для написания web сервера на чистом C, но на практике не доводилось использовать. Так как пишу на С++. Поэтому не могу ничего сказать по нему.